# XSD structure to CSV as path,type,cardinality

Tags: csv, xsd

I need XSD unloaded into CSV file to build a mapping doc. The CSV is a list of all tags defined in XSD, in format path,type,cardinality. Something like:

```
tag1/tag2/tag3,E,0..n
tag1/tag2/tag3@attr1,A,0..n
tag1/tag2/tag4,E,1..1
```

XSD may import schemas. Is there a tool to accomplish this task? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote one that generates an Excel spreadsheet - shouldn't be a problem to get it to do CSV directly. The exported path is a true XPath: it'll add namespace prefixes (as defined by the user), xsi:type attributes for type hierarchies based on elements with an abstract type, etc. Is this for a one time job, or to be incorporated as part of an automatic build process?

Comment: well, this is a one time job, I would say

Comment: Ok, if you're still interested, please let me know (sorry, had other things to attend to...) I can provide you with a download link and then I'll email you a paper describing the steps involved, and a sample XML Schema. I'm not sure what your expectations are vis-a-vis the cardinality value; things can get very tricky with compositors, not to mention for which relationship it applies; e.g. tag3 to tag2 or tag3 to tag1? how about choices? etc.

Comment: yes, I'm interested, have not found proper solution yet. I will be grateful for your link. I see your point regarding cardinality value. My expectation was very basic: mentioning relation to the 'closest' tag would be fine. For more broader specification user may study XSD itself. Thank you, Petru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a possible solution [here](http://paschidev.com/downloads/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality.pdf). If it is something you're willing to try, then download the tool and the sample files; please follow the document for step by step guidance. If you run into any issues, send me an email using the contact info (support) on the web site.

The cardinality problem, again, is very tricky. The sample I've prepared for you (all the download links are in the document) is one of the test cases I was using, except that I had to come up with a specific template for your file layout. One issue that seems to be subject to debate is how to calculate the value for XPaths that, from an XML Schema perspective, traverse choice compositors. Another, not so controversial maybe, is how to calculate the cardinality for particles under repeating compositors, etc.

Comment: Petru, thank you. I've downloaded tool and it did worked great with provided samples. However, I hit some issue with my work schemas. The case and files are sent on support email. I really appreciate if you have a minute to take a look on it.

Comment: Splendid, it worked :) a great tool indeed and helped me finally out. Thank you a lot for your answer and support. Really appreciate.

Comment: a thing more: is it possible to display the cardinality of sublevel tag? E.g. if input is tag1/tag2/tag3, then documentation shows

tag1/tag2 E 0..1
tag1/tag2/tag3 E 0..1