# Get list of XSD elements in C#

Tags: c#, xsd

I have an XSD file and want to get a list of the names of all the elements in it. I don't mean stuff like `<xs:sequence>` and so on, just the "real stuff", that actually can appear in XML that are valid according to the XSD.

Comment: Can you please include an example of the XSD file you're trying to process?

Comment: sure: http://www.uloz.to/11605646/ships-xsd (in case the site is not in english, there's some language switch at the right top corner)

Comment: If all else fails, remember that XSDs is itself XML, so you can read it as such and extract the information you need manually.

Comment: I know that, but am looking for some more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Real stuff is a bit vague

But if you just want want all elements it's just a it of Xpath.

If you want a tree, then you can't avoid sequence etc.
If you have things like xs:choice in there you have even more issues.

Then there's attributes...

From SimpleContent or ComplexType...

Might be easier to generate a 'blank' xml document from the xsd and then get what you want out of that. That's a fair chunk of code as well though. Might be one lying around you can borrow though.

Comment: I dont need a tree, no xs:xhoice, no attributes

Comment: It's a simple xpath query for the name attribute of every element node then, can't see why the problem is worth any more effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually want to do this from your code, you could use the [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to create source code for runtime objects.

From there you can use Xml serialization to create valid Xml samples for your given Xsd schema.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to code for this, I would assume you want to do this against different XML Schema files, over and over; if true, it would be then important to understand if you really have to embed this in your codebase, or if it can be used as an external tool.

If you really want to do it, most of all you need is in System.Xml.Schema package. Start with an [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx) to load and compile your XSD files. Then using an iterator on [GlobalElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.globalelements%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), go over the global elements that can show as your root elements in XML document and traverse those (for what you need, use the PSVI properties); as someone else was mentioning, there will be types to go through, compositors, etc.; and then there's more: abstract elements (those can't show up in XML, neither references to abstract elements, instead members of substitution groups), prohibited attributes, restricted types, etc.

I've recently answered [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378648/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality) that may be related to your need; your posted XML Schema may look like this:

```
root/ship/engine/@MaxSpeed,A,1..1,True
root/ship/crew/@function,A,1..1,True
root/ship/@Name,A,1..1,True
root/ship/@class,A,1..1,True
root/ship/special_abilities/hull/@separable,A,0..1,False
root/ship/special_abilities/hull/@canCarryWesley,A,0..1,False
root/ship/special_abilities/hull/@capableOfLanding,A,0..1,False
```

If you want, you can deal only with the first column; the generated XPath shows only those items (elements or attributes) that have data; processing something like the above might be much easier (split the string using /, elements are all but @, etc.)