# extract paths from xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Let's say I have the following XML document:

```
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <bang bash="hello">
    <foobar>123</foobar>
  </bang>
</foo>
```

I want to extract the list of all paths to the various leaves in this document, for instance:

```
foo
foo.bar
foo.bang
foo.bang.@bash
foo.bang.foobar
```

Is there a term for this process?

Take this a step further: let's say I have an .xsd for a truly monstrously complex XML schema. Is there an easy way to extract all such paths from the .xsd?

(by easy way, ideally I mean does a library to do this exist somewhere?)

Comment: bonus points if data-type information is included (foo:complex, foo.bang.bash:String, foo.bang.foobar:int, etc)

Comment: If you can use .NET then the `GetExpectedParticles` method of XmlSchemaValidator can be used to descend from the root element - this will be complex though, as shown in this previous [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6827151/63965)

Comment: Saxon's [Schema Component Model API](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/index.html#!javadoc/com.saxonica.schema) may be useful here also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564987/create-xpath-from-xsd-in-java/9566441#9566441) was posted here on SO. I am still not aware of any out of the box solution (API or otherwise) for your scenario, other than the one I've described in the related post.

I am the first to recognize that even [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378648/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality) I've described on SO may lack coverage for certain XSD features, or may not match one's specific expectation on how certain XPaths should be generated. It can support things from your updated request (to include additional "metadata", such as the type of the node matched by an XPath) since a computed column can be added with a custom formula to match your pattern.

While the algorithm described by C. M. Sperberg-McQueen definitely gives you an idea about some of the things it may involve, it is also framed by a gentle "disclaimer" regarding the simple-minded approach, which really means that a number of scenarios covered by the XSD spec was left out.

Unless your XSD is really simple, consider that a teaser! Some "bad" examples: recursive XML structures (alluded to) through complex types (not only element references) is tricky, more so when type hierarchies are heavy and pervasive in the design of the XSD; use of abstract typed elements (think xsi:type attributes in instance XML), use of the block attribute, the form attribute, the use of chameleon XSDs (now step 1 is all fun just by itself, not to mention if different defaults are used for element/attribute forms at the schema level).

If you find that some of these extra "details" are applicable to your XSDs, then I would recommend to forget about XQuery or XSLT and use a specialized Schema Object Model API (XSOM on Java, .NET also has a very good one) to traverse your XSD - here I just repeated what @pgfearo said with a twist (from what I know, SAXON XSD support is available in the paid edition only; while Apache and JAXB RI provide you with an XSOM for free). You wouldn't need to worry about many things then, and most likely you'll be able to do it in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

In the SGML community, the values you are looking for were referred to (when they involved elements) as "fully qualified generic identifiers" or FQGIs; because '.' is a legal name character in XML and in the SGML reference concrete syntax, FQGIs are normally written with slashes where you are writing dots.  (I'll stretch the term FQGI here and use it to denote the strings you're interested in, including the ones that denote attributes, not elements.)

I don't know of any established term for the process of finding the set of all FQGIs which could possibly appear in documents valid against a particular schema.  Bear in mind that in many XML vocabularies this is an infinite set; if you want a process that terminates, you will need to identify a finite subset of all possible FQGIs.

But the process you need to follow is relatively simple.  A simple-minded version runs like this:

1. If the schema you are interested in is defined across multiple schema documents, bring them all together into either a single XML document (a wrapper with multiple xs:schema children) or a single collection of schema documents which can be processed using XSLT or XQuery.
2. Identify the set of element declarations and attribute declarations you wish to start from.  (In your case, this set presumably consists of the top-level element declaration for foo.)  For each item in this set write down its name and its type.  Call this set of string / type pairs S.
3. Copy set S into a set S'.
4. Create a set S'' in the following way:  start with S'' empty, then for each item in S', let N be the FQGI and T the type named in the item, and:

   (a) If N denotes an attribute, then do nothing.

   (b) If N denotes an element, then identify the set of attributes that that could appear on such an element.  For each such attribute, identify its type T2, and create a string N2 by concatenating N, a slash, an at-sign, and the expanded name of the attribute.  Add the pair (N2, T2) to S''.

   (c) If N denotes an element, then find the set of elements which (i) appear in the content model for T, (ii) match a wildcard in the content model of T, or (iii) are substitutable for elements named in (i) or (ii).  For each such possible child, identify the child's type T3 and make a string N3 by concatenating N, "/", and the expanded name of the possible child.  Add the pair (N3, T3) to S''.
5. If S'' is empty, you are done and your answer is in the union of set S and set S'.  Otherwise, let (a new) S be the union of S and S', let (a new) S' be equal to S'', and go to step 4.

A little reflection will tell you that the set of names which can match wildcards is infinite, so list (ii) in step 4(c) cannot be processed in full.  You can choose a finite subset of the list in various ways; which you choose depends on what you want the list of FQGIs for.

A little more reflection will tell you that if any element in the vocabulary can appear as its own descendant (like HTML's div or li elements), the process outlined will never terminate.  Again, there are a variety of ways you can trim the set of pairs generated in 4(c) to guarantee termination.

I don't know of any library that does this, perhaps because the set of possible FQGIs is so seldom finite for interesting XML vocabularies. It's easy enough to do the work with an XQuery engine or in an XSLT stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Java tool [XsdPathTypeGenerator](https://github.com/linus1412/XsdPathTypeGenerator) to do this.  It also extracts the element and attribute types.

Given an XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://smitek.co.uk/example/1">
    <xsd:element name="employee">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="department">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="active" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

It will create a Map

```
employee@active=xsd:boolean
employee/name=xsd:string
employee/department@code=xsd:decimal
employee/department/name=xsd:string
```

It has certain limitations which mean you run it as a tool rather than use it as a library, do to me being lazy, but it solved my problem at least :)