# XSD.exe missing nested properties

Tags: c#, xslt, xsd

I have a flattened XSD here:
http://pastebin.com/tQVSH9Jp

I have a 'substitution' XSLT script I am running against it to fix it for XSD.exe (which ignores referenced elements), however the resultant XSD is missing a few properties. (`ID` is not present in `UniqueID_Type`).

Can anyone provide an XSLT script that will correctly perform these substitutions, or even provide another solution altogether?

Comment: Are you aware that `xsd.exe` is just a thin wrapper around the framework classes (`XmlSchema`, `XmlSchemaImporter`, `XmlCodeExporter`, `CodeDomProvider`) and that you can very easily write your own `xsd.exe`, to emit any code style and any fancy features that you'd like to see in the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's funny that someone suggested to write your own xsd.exe, and also to rely on XmlSchemaImporter... For one, I don't think it is a trivial task; secondly, the problem with the missing attribute comes from [XmlSchemaImporter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaimporter.aspx); there's a bug in ImportAttributeGroupMembers: instead of looking for an XmlSchemaAttributeGroupRef, it is checking for an XmlSchemaAttributeGroup (excerpt below courtesy of Reflector):

```
private void ImportAttributeGroupMembers(XmlSchemaAttributeGroup group, string identifier, CodeIdentifiers members, CodeIdentifiers membersScope, string ns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < group.Attributes.Count; i++)
    {
        object obj2 = group.Attributes[i];
        if (obj2 is XmlSchemaAttributeGroup)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (obj2 is XmlSchemaAttribute)
        {
           ...
        }
     }
     ...
}
```

There's a similar utility, [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) which I would try with the original XSD before going into XML Schema Refactoring (XSR).

If you want to go down this route, I recommend [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) for XSR (I am associated with it). I've tried your XSD with the latest version (4.0.21) and it worked. I've posted the result [here](http://pastebin.com/DeSRpigz).

The generated code using XSD.exe for the fragment you pointed out as defective (I am just showing the fields) now shows the idField for the ID attribute:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public partial class UniqueID_Type {

    private CompanyNameType companyNameField;

    private string uRLField;

    private string typeField;

    private string instanceField;

    private string idField;

    private string iD_ContextField;

    ...
}
```

What's specific for your setup is the InlineAttributeGroups that must be set to true:

[image: QTAssistant setting InlineAttributeGroups]

If you're interested in more details about refactoring using QTAssistant, please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378648/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality), also on SO. Anyway, I've posted the entire refactored schema, feel free to use it...

Comment: Thankyou so much! That generated .xsd file works great in xsd.exe.


Ive downloaded QTAssistant and opened my original XSD to attempt to replicate your fix, but cannot seem to do it. Can you outline the steps you took in QTAssistant?

Comment: @maxp, yes, I'll post a document with all the steps for your particular setup; just let me know first if this one (for another post on SO) doesn't work for you: http://paschidev.com/downloads/xsd-structure-to-csv-as-path-type-cardinality.pdf

Comment: Hi Petru, I tried to follow it but got a bit confused half way through.
Am I supposed to first create a XSR? I tried to use the '.NET xsd.exe' tool link and 'Select file set' always came up empty? I got lost so a 'howto' document would be great.

Comment: @maxp, I'll make one specifically; I can only do it later on in the day, I hope it is OK with you.

Comment: @maxp, I need a  bit more time, I've ran into a couple of issues with the OTA standard that I've decided to also document for your future reference; I am thinking no later than noon today.

Comment: @maxp, all is now available. The doc showing what I've mentioned is available at this [link](http://paschidev.com/downloads/xsd-exe-missing-nested-properties.pdf). You would also need to download an update (use the automatic update feature or download the setup again) to get in 4.0.22; I've added a new report to deal with OTA 2011B release that seems, in my opinion, buggy; nonetheless, it provided a good example that called for new features and fixes.

Comment: Hi Petru, I've just tried it, and it works great. Thank you so much for taking the time. Drop me a message when your ecommerce shop is up.
I noted at the end of the PDF you mentioned issues with generating the entire OTA library in one large XSD. Did you conclude this was not possible?

Comment: Hi @maxp, no, it is possible except for a couple of files (two XSDs mentioned) that need to be separated from the rest. I was intending to send them a note to fix for the next release... Thank you.

Comment: I sent you a message regarding purchasing qtassitant as the trial has expired. Could you check your spam filter?

Comment: @maxp, please confirm if this is about an email you've sent May 15th. If yes, then I'll resend. Thank you...

Comment: Thats the one! Did your reply get spam filtered?